# How to apply conditional formatting to compare ratings vba excel?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am comparing credit ratings from Today to Yesterday and if there has been a change, positive, the cell should go green and red for any negative changes on Excel

I have been trying to use various formulas with conditional formatting and if statements

```
ID  S&P Moody's ID
1   AAA Aaa 1
1   AAA- *- Aaa- *- 1
2   AA+ Aa1 2
2   AA+ *-  Aa1 *-  2
2   AA+ *+  Aa1 *+  2
3   AA  Aa2 3
3   AA *-   Aa2 *-  3
3   AA *+   Aa2 *+  3
4   AA- Aa3 4
4   AA- *-  Aa3 *-  4
4   AA- *+  Aa3 *+  4
```

I have done the rankings by number - so the lower the better.

Comment: Could you show us the code that you tried so far and where you got stuck on? We can't help you properly if you don't show what you tried.

Comment: Hi erazorv4, - having thought about it it will actually be a conditional format right :( just figuringout what formula to put in

Comment: Can you show us how your data is formatted originally? It's unclear how you comparing today vs yesteray with the sample data you now provided.

Comment: Rating Today: AAA | Rating Yesterday: AAA-.  This is how it would look. As can be seen by the above table this is a positive change